# In Python how do I make a copy of a numpy Matrix column such that any further operations to the copy does not affect the original matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, copy

I would normally copy a whole matrix as follows:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy
b=np.array([[2,3],[1,2]])
a = np.empty_like (b)
a[:] = b
```

(Note a and b are not what I am using in my code and are just made up for this example). But how do I copy just the first column (or any selected column) of a matrix so that when operated on it does not affect the original column?

PS. I am new so sorry If I am making a really stupid error but I really have searched for the solution a long time

Answer (score 1):

Just use indexing to slice a column then use `copy()` attribute of array object to create a copy:

```
>>> b=np.array([[2,3],[1,2]])
>>> b
array([[2, 3],
       [1, 2]])
>>> a = b[:,0].copy()
>>> a
array([2, 1])
>>> a += 2
>>> a
array([4, 3])
>>> b
array([[2, 3],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kasramvd but using your copy() idea is there any problem with doing the following:

    `a=np.copy(b[:,0])`

Comment: @l.stewie - did you try it?

Comment: @l.stewie No there is not!